# I am looking at an iterative solution of checking whether a tree is symmetric

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, iteration

I have the following code:

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.left = this.right = null
    }
}

const isSymmetric = root => {
    if (!root) return true
    let stackP = []
    let stackQ = []
    let currentP = root
    let currentQ = root

    while ((currentP && currentQ) || (stackP.length && stackQ.length)) {

        while (currentP) {
            stackP.push(currentP)
            currentP = currentP.left
        }
        while (currentQ) {
            stackQ.push(currentQ)
            currentQ = currentQ.right
        }

        console.log(stackP, stackQ, 'after push')

        currentP = stackP.pop()
        currentQ = stackQ.pop()
        console.log(stackP, stackQ, 'after 1 iterative pop')

        if ((currentP.val !== currentQ.val) || (stackP.length !== stackQ.length)) return false
        console.log(currentP, currentQ, 'after if statement')

        // confused as to why we are setting it to the opposite here
        currentP = currentP.right
        currentQ = currentQ.left


        console.log(currentP, currentQ, 'after opp DECLARATION')
    }
    return true
}

//example 1
const tree1 = new TreeNode(1)
tree1.left = new TreeNode(2)
tree1.right = new TreeNode(2)

tree1.left.left = new TreeNode(3)
tree1.left.right = new TreeNode(4)

tree1.right.left = new TreeNode(4)
tree1.right.right = new TreeNode(3)

//example 2
const tree2 = new TreeNode(1)
tree2.left = new TreeNode(2)
tree2.right = new TreeNode(2)

tree2.left.right = new TreeNode(3)

tree2.right.right = new TreeNode(3)

console.log(isSymmetric(tree1));
console.log(isSymmetric(tree2));
```

However, I am confused with the following two lines:

```
currentP = currentP.right
currentQ = currentQ.left
```

I am not sure why this is done.  I tried following along with console logging, but am not able to follow.  I would expect `currentP` to maintain itself following the original pattern which is set to the left, but it seems after popping the `P` and `Q` they are now traversing to the right.  I don't understand why.  Can anyone clarify?

let's say we have the following tree

```
   A 
  / \ 
 B   B 
/ \ / \ 
C D D C
```

tracking `currentP` and `currentQ` should give the following values A, B, C, C, null, B, D, null, A. But when we get to A flowing through the logic it seems we are in an infinite loop. Unless I am not tracking it correctly. After we declare `currentP` and `currentQ` to be 'A' we should enter the while loops again, essentially pushing B and C back again, am I missing something?

Comment: Just consider the right and left subtrees of the root as two distinct trees. Then, do a traversal through both at the same time, if at any moment they diverge, you have your answer. It's like performing a DFS in two trees at once, if at some moment a node is null and the other is not, then you found a difference. You can do it iteratively, but recursively seems easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this tree:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
/ \ / \
D E F G
```

First it walks all the way to the left (stackP = B, D) stacking them, and to the right (stackQ = C, G). Then compare the last leafs (D, G). Then take their siblings (E, F) and compare - *That's the part you were talking about*. Then pop their parents (B, C) and compare.

Here's the program with some debug info that will give you a better idea of what it is doing:

```js
class TreeNode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
  }
}

function serialize(arr) {
  return arr.map(e => e.val).join(",");
}

const isSymmetric = (root) => {
  if (!root) return true;
  let stackP = [];
  let stackQ = [];
  let currentP = root;
  let currentQ = root;

  while ((currentP && currentQ) || (stackP.length && stackQ.length)) {
    while (currentP) {
      stackP.push(currentP);
      console.log(`Pushing ${currentP.val} to sP=[${serialize(stackP)}]`)
      currentP = currentP.left;
    }
    while (currentQ) {
      stackQ.push(currentQ);
      console.log(`Pushing ${currentQ.val} to sQ=[${serialize(stackQ)}]`)
      currentQ = currentQ.right;
    }

    currentP = stackP.pop();
    currentQ = stackQ.pop();

    console.log(`Comparing cP=${currentP.val} cQ=${currentQ.val} sP=[${serialize(stackP)}] sQ=[${serialize(stackQ)}]`);

    if (currentP.val !== currentQ.val || stackP.length !== stackQ.length)
      return false;

    // confused as to why we are setting it to the opposite here
    currentP = currentP.right;
    currentQ = currentQ.left;

    console.log(`Looping   cP=${currentP ? currentP.val : "null"} cQ=${currentQ ? currentQ.val : "null"} sP=[${serialize(stackP)}] sQ=[${serialize(stackQ)}]`);
  }
  return true;
};

//example 1
const tree1 = new TreeNode(1)
tree1.left = new TreeNode(2)
tree1.right = new TreeNode(2)

tree1.left.left = new TreeNode(3)
tree1.left.right = new TreeNode(4)

tree1.right.left = new TreeNode(4)
tree1.right.right = new TreeNode(3)

//example 2
const tree2 = new TreeNode(1)
tree2.left = new TreeNode(2)
tree2.right = new TreeNode(2)

tree2.left.right = new TreeNode(3)

tree2.right.right = new TreeNode(3)

console.log(isSymmetric(tree1));
console.log(isSymmetric(tree2));
```

Comment: Tracking 'currentP' and 'currentQ' should give the following values A, B, C, C, null, B, D, null, A. But when we get to A flowing through the logic it seems we are in an infinite loop. Unless I am not tracking it correctly. After we declare 'currentP' and 'currentQ' to be 'A' we should enter the while loops again, essentially pushing B and C back again, am I missing something?

Comment: added the tree to the question description

Comment: Updated with some better debug info